# Rcpp: Recommended code structure when using data frames with Rcpp (inline)

Tags: c++, r, data-structures, dataframe, rcpp

[I had this sketched out as a comment elsewhere but decided to create a proper question...]

What is currently considered "best practice" in terms of code structuring when using data frames in Rcpp? The ease with which one can "beam over" an input data frame from R to the C++ code is remarkable, but if the data frame has n columns, **is the current thinking that this data should be split up into n separate (C++) vectors before being used?**

The response to my previous question on making use of a string (character vector) column in a data frame suggests to me that yes, this is the right thing to do. In particular, **there doesn't seem to be support for a notation such as df.name[i]** to refer to the data frame information directly (as one might have in a C structure), unless I'm mistaken.

However, this leads us into a situation where subsetting down the data is much more cumbersome - instead of being able to subset a data frame in one line, each variable must be dealt with separately. So, **is the thinking that subsetting in Rcpp is best done implicitly, via boolean vectors, say?**

To summarise, I guess in a nutshell I wanted to check my current understanding that although a data frame can be beamed over to the C++ code, there is no way to refer directly to the individual elements of its columns in a "df.name[i]" fashion, and no simple method of generating a sub-dataframe of the input df by selecting rows satisfying simple criteria (e.g. df.date being in a given range).

Comment: Not really what you're asking, but as an aside maybe the [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) source code in C gives some clues about one way to manipulate data.frame at the C level. I don't know if it's similar in C++.

Comment: Pretty sure Rcpp has a Rcpp::DataFrame

Comment: @Hansi, there is and that is what Tim is using.

Comment: Exactly. I'm using Rcpp::DataFrame. But there doesn't seem to be a way to refer to the element data without first redefining the columns as separate vectors (unless I'm mistaken)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because data frames are in fact internally represented as list of vectors, the access by vectors really is the best you can do.  There simply is no way to subset by row at the C or C++ level.

There was a good discussion about that on r-devel a few weeks ago in the context of a transpose of a data.frame (which you cannot do 'cheaply' for the same reason).

Comment: Thanks Dirk - though couldn't find the discussion you mentioned? Am I right in thinking then that boolean vectors are the best way to consider different subsets of the data frame within the C++ code?

Comment: Re the r-devel discussion: look for a thread with Antonio Piccolboni and Simon Urbanek. As for the boolean indexing, I am not sure if we ever implemented that. If in doubt, do it "manually" via index positions as that is how the C++ vectors work natively.

Comment: For the benefit of others, here's Dirk's thread: [link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/fast-version-of-split-data-frame-or-conversion-from-data-frame-to-list-of-its-rows-td4599769.html) What's really interesting is that the "struct" approach - thinking of the data as an array of rows - is widely considered best practice for C-style coding involving this kind of data ([link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson7.html)), to ensure the values in a row are always "bound together". In Rcpp the design is orthogonal to this (literally!) since a df is considered as a list of columns.

Comment: R data structures happen to be vectors, and lists. Even a matrix is just a vector of size 'n times k' with dimension attributes 'n, k'.

Comment: Agreed, although given that's the case, it seems strange that there is no notation to pull out the third element (say) of column "age" in an Rcpp data frame object by naming the vector and then the element. I understand that `DF["age"]` gives the column vector (as we can assign it to another variable, `age`), but isn't there a way of pulling out `df$age[3]` as, I don't know, `(DF["age"])[2]` in Rcpp?

Comment: Well, if *you* need that notation so badly, how about if *you* contribute the patch to implement it?

Comment: As I only learnt of Rcpp a couple of days ago, and my eyes glaze over at complex C++ code (I'm primarily an R coder), I'm pretty sure I'm not the right person to write the required patch. I'm afraid I'll have to leave my contribution at highlighting the need for it...!